# Writing the following query using relational algebra

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-algebra

I am trying to write the following query using the relational algebra:

```
"Find the names of sailors who reserved a red or a green boat"
```

Here is my solution:
[image]

But the book gives the following solution:
[image]

And another equivalent solution given by book:
[image]

End here is the related tables:
[image]

My question is, can't we use the "or" symbol (V) in selection operator? Is my solution wrong? Why do we need renaming operator?

Thanks

Comment: What book is this (out of curiosity?)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet more proof that there is no such thing as "the" relational algebra.

As for restriction :

Your book/teacher seems to go by the principle that restriction conditions can only be "very basic".  In the sense as the wiki article on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_%28relational_algebra%29 (at least one attribute referenced, one other attribute or constant value, only one single comparison operator involved, no other operator invocations allowed such as SIN(angle attr) or MONTH(datetime attr) or ...).

But that restriction (on the restrict condition) is unnecessary.  The wiki article about relational algebra on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Selection_.28.CF.83.29 says explicitly "... is a propositional formula that consists of ... and the logical operators AND,OR,NOT ...".

As for rename :

The RENAME operator in relational algebra is used to yield a relation value that differs from the input only in that certain **attributes** have "changed name".

Your book/teacher apparently uses an operator called "rename" to **assign a name** to some specified **relational expression** (a UNION in your example).  That isn't even an algebraic operation !!!

(While it is a valid and useful idea in language design to devise a possibility for the user to have "named expressions", that he can subsequently reference using just the assigned name, this is a matter of **language design, not of relational algebra** !)

Comment: There are a lot of textbook "algebra"s. (SQL-apologetics ones are really *languages*.) "Very basic" is *better*. Expressions nest calls to operators on attribute X theta X attribute X relation & attribute X theta X value X relation. But for arbitrary formulas you need either a formula sort & an operator on formula X relation or something like an operator per formula. (And for function symbols....) This begs the question of what an algebra is for. It's algebraic predicate logic. So leave formulas to predicate logic. (Theta too--have EXTEND by an attribute/constant. And functions as relations.)

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code, in my phpmyadmin and it must be work

**Select all sailors who reserves, while the boats already created;**

```
SELECT * FROM sailors INNER JOIN reserves ON reserves.sid = sailors.sid LEFT JOIN boats ON reserves.bid = boats.bid
```

**Specific Selection(Color:Red);**

using WHERE color = 'red'

```
SELECT * FROM sailors INNER JOIN reserves ON reserves.sid = sailors.sid LEFT JOIN boats ON reserves.bid = boats.bid WHERE color = 'red'
```

**Multi Selection(Color:Red and Blue);**

using WHERE color = 'red' **or** 'blue'

```
SELECT * FROM sailors INNER JOIN reserves ON reserves.sid = sailors.sid LEFT JOIN boats ON reserves.bid = boats.bid WHERE color = 'red' or 'blue'
```