# What is the relational algebra of the "IN" and "NOT IN" query?

Tags: sql, algebra

What is the relational algebra of the `IN()` / `NOT IN()` query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849160/writing-the-following-query-using-relational-algebra

Comment: For your paper? Please...

Answer (score 2):

IN is basically OR, f.ex:

```
x IN (1,2,3)
```

is

```
x=1 OR x=2 OR x=3
```

NOT IN is just negation of it, so

```
x NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

is

```
NOT (x=1 OR x=2 OR x=3)
```

or following boolean logic

```
x<>1 AND x<>2 AND x<>3
```